# char = 0 in c++ using XOR

Tags: c++, string

I am practicing string manipulation in C++ and found this example that finds the difference between 2 strings and returns that character. Here is that code.

```
#include <iostream>

char find_difference(const std::string& s, const std::string& t)
{
    std::string r = s + t;
    char ch = 0;
    for (char c : r) {
        ch ^= c;
    }
    return ch;
}
```

They are using XOR here which makes sense in theory, but I am a bit confused on the implementation. Firstly, what does this mean?

```
char ch = 0;
```

I know "^=" means XOR, but how does iterating through the string with char ch = 0, give accurate results?

Comment: It's not clear what this function would be useful for.

Comment: what is the difference of two strings in this question? can you show an example?

Answer (score 1):

This implementation you have will work ONLY if there a single different character, and both strings are totally same otherwise. It's based on the assumption that both strings are same, but one character, so if you XOR any character with itself you'll get `0` (zero), so they XOR all characters together, same characters will cancel themselves out and the only result left would be the XOR between different character in one string and different character in another string.

It might be even not a printable character, for example 'a' ^ 'b' will give you '\x01', and so on. So I don't quite understand why someone will write this silly code and what purpose it can be used for.

And what more... XOR operation does not care about the order. If you have strings 'abc' and 'cab' -- this function won't find any difference.

Comment: I think it is an interview style question.. but seems this is not the best approach for finding the difference between strings.

Comment: Though, do you think this is the best approach if the question specifically states there are 2 strings that are equal besides 1 character, what is that character? Or even then, would a different approach make more sense?

Comment: @grizzleKat456 I don't know, current approach will say `aaaa` and `bbbb` are not different, which is a bit odd. The only thing it's good for -- comparing the strings that are totally same (ignoring the order of characters) except one extra character somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly, what does this mean?
>
> ```
> char ch = 0;
> ```

It declares a variable of type `char` and initialises it to the value 0.

> how does iterating through the string with char ch = 0, give accurate results?

Think about what 0 XOR c means. What is the result? I'll spoil the answer: The result is c. Mathematically speaking, 0 is the unity element of the XOR operation. So, adding a 0 to the beginning of the iterated sequence does not change the result - letting us write the loop differently.

This is essentially performing the a left fold with the XOR operation. It *could* be done by initialising the accumulator with the first element, and then iterating the rest of the elements, but expressing the loop from second element to last is much less convenient than a loop over every element because of the range-for syntax. As such, initialising the accumulator with the unity (0) produces more readable code.

Furthermore, this conveniently correctly handles the case where inputs are empty, in which case there would not be a first which could thus not be used to initialise ch.